# Swift Mini-Max Sum One Test Case Failed - HackerRank

Tags: swift, algorithm

Before anything else, I checked if this kind of question fits Stackoverflow, and based on one similar question (javascript) and from this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on -- it does.

So here it goes. The challenge is pretty simple, in my opinion:

> Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that
>   can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then
>   print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of
>   two space-separated long integers.
>
> For example, . Our minimum sum is  and our maximum sum is . We would
>   print
>
> `16 24`

**Input Constraint:**
`1 <= arr[i] <= (10^9)`

My solution is pretty simple. This is what I could do best:

```
func miniMaxSum(arr: [Int]) -> Void {
    let sorted = arr.sorted()
    let reversed = Array(sorted.reversed())
    var minSum = 0
    var maxSum = 0

    _ = sorted
        .filter({ $0 != sorted.last!})
        .map { minSum += $0 }  
    _ = reversed
        .filter({ $0 != reversed.last!})
        .map { maxSum += $0 }    

    print("\(minSum) \(maxSum)")
}
```

As you can see, I have two sorted arrays. One is incrementing, and the other one is decrementing. And I'm removing the last element of the two newly sorted arrays. The way I remove the last element is using `filter`, which probably creates the problem. But from there, I thought I could get easily the minimum and maximum sum of the 4 elements.

I had 13/14 test cases passed. And my question is, what could be the test case in which this solution will likely to fail?

Problem link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem

Comment: You should link to the question on HackerRank, so people can try it more easily

Comment: Yep, added it!.

Comment: Are you getting a wrong error or a time out?

Comment: @MartinR Oops, haven't tried it yet. With Timsort, should we consider the accepted answer as O(nLog(n)) (worst case) or O(n)? The O(n) solution shouldn't sort, and it takes into consideration that 4 = 5 - 1

Comment: @ielyamani: The question was “Why does this code fail a test case?” and not “What is the fastest solution for this programming challenge?” – I intentionally did not provide a full solution, so that OP is not deprived from the satisfaction to solve that challenge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this isn't codereview.stackexchange.com, but I think some clean up is in order, so I'll start with that.

1. `let reversed = Array(sorted.reversed())`

   The whole point of the `ReversedCollection` that is returned by `Array.reversed()` is that it doesn't cause a copy of elements, and it doesn't take up any extra memory or time to produce. It's merely a wrapper around a collection, and intercepts indexing operations and changes them to immitate a buffer that's been reversed. Asked for `.first`? It'll give you `.last` of its wrapped collection. Asked for `.last`? It'll return `.first`, etc.

   By initializing a new `Array` from `sorted.reversed()`, you're causing an unecessary copy, and defeating the point of `ReversedCollection`. There are some circumstances where this might be necessary (e.g. you want to pass a pointer to a buffer of reversed elements to a C API), but this isn't one of them.

   So we can just change that to `let reversed = sorted.reversed()`
2. `-> Void` doesn't do anything, omit it.
3. `sorted.filter({ $0 != sorted.last!})` is inefficient.

   ... but more than that, this is the source of your error. There's a bug in this. If you have an array like `[1, 1, 2, 3, 3]`, your `minSum` will be `4` (the sum of `[1, 1, 2]`), when it should be `7` (the sum of `[1, 1, 2, 3]`). Similarly, the `maxSum` will be `8` (the sume of `[2, 3, 3]`) rather than `9` (the sum of `[1, 2, 3, 3]`).

   You're doing a scan of the whole array, doing `sorted.count` equality checks, only to discard an element with a known position (the last element). Instead, use `dropLast()`, which returns a collection that wraps the input, but whose operations mask the existing of a last element.

   ```
   _ = sorted
       .dropLast()
       .map { minSum += $0 }      
   _ = reversed
       .dropLast()
       .map { maxSum += $0 }
   ```
4. `_ = someCollection.map(f)`

   ... is an anti-pattern. The distinguishing feature between `map` and `forEach` is that it produces a resulting array that stores the return values of the closure as evaluated with every input element. If you're not going to use the result, use `forEach`

   ```
   sorted.dropLast().forEach { minSum += $0 }  
   reversed.dropLast().forEach { maxSum += $0 }
   ```

   However, there's an even better way. Rather than summing by mutating a variable and manually adding to it, instead use `reduce` to do so. This is ideal because it allows you to remove the mutability of `minSum` and `maxSum`.

   ```
   let minSum = sorted.dropLast().reduce(0, +)
   let maxSum = reversed.dropLast().reduce(0, +)
   ```
5. You don't really need the `reversed` variable at all. You could just achieve the same thing by operating over `sorted` and using `dropFirst()` instead of `dropLast()`:

   ```
   func miniMaxSum(arr: [Int]) {
       let sorted = arr.sorted()

       let minSum = sorted.dropLast().reduce(0, +)
       let maxSum = sorted.dropFirst().reduce(0, +)

       print("\(minSum) \(maxSum)")
   }
   ```
6. Your code assumes the input size is always 5. It's good to document that in the code:

   ```
   func miniMaxSum(arr: [Int]) {
       assert(arr.count == 5)

       let sorted = arr.sorted()

       let minSum = sorted.dropLast().reduce(0, +)
       let maxSum = sorted.dropFirst().reduce(0, +)

       print("\(minSum) \(maxSum)")
   }
   ```
7. A generalization of your solution uses a lot of extra memory, which you might not have available to you.

   This problem fixes the number of summed numbers (always 4) and the number of input numbers (always 5). This problem could be generalized to picking `summedElementCount` numbers out of any sized `arr`. In this case, sorting and summing twice is inefficient:

   - Your solution has a space complexity of `O(arr.count)`

     - This is caused by the need to hold the sorted array. If you were allowed to mutate `arr` in-place, this could reduce to `O(1).
   - Your solution has a time complexity of `O((arr.count * log_2(arr.count)) + summedElementCount)`

     - Derivation: Sorting first (which takes `O(arr.count * log_2(arr.count))`), and then summing the first and last `summedElementCount` (which is each `O(summedElementCount)`)

       ```
         O(arr.count * log_2(arr.count)) + (2 * O(summedElementCount))
       = O(arr.count * log_2(arr.count)) + O(summedElementCount) // Annihilation of multiplication by a constant factor
       = O((arr.count * log_2(arr.count)) + summedElementCount) // Addition law for big O
       ```

   This problem could instead be solved with a bounded priority queue, like the `MinMaxPriorityQueue` in Google's Gauva library for Java. It's simply a wrapper for [min-max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap) that maintains a fixed number of elements, that when added to, causes the greatest element (according to the provided comparator) to be evicted. If you had something like this available to you in Swift, you could do:

   ```
   func miniMaxSum(arr: [Int], summedElementCount: Int) {
       let minQueue = MinMaxPriorityQueue<Int>(size: summedElementCount, comparator: <)
       let maxQueue = MinMaxPriorityQueue<Int>(size: summedElementCount, comparator: >)

       for i in arr {
           minQueue.offer(i)
           maxQueue.offer(i)
       }

       let (minSum, maxSum) = (minQueue.reduce(0, +), maxQueue.reduce(0, +))

       print("\(minSum) \(maxSum)")
   }
   ```

   - This solution has a space complexity of only `O(summedElementCount)` extra space, needed to hold the two queues, each of max size `summedElementCount`.

     - This is less than  the previous solution, because `summedElementCount <= arr.count`
   - This solution has a time complexity of `O(arr.count * log_2(summedElementCount))`

     - Derviation: The for loop does `arr.count` iterations, each consisting of a `log_2(summedElementCount)` operation on both queues.

       ```
         O(arr.count) * (2 * O(log_2(summedElementCount)))
       = O(arr.count) * O(log_2(summedElementCount)) // Annihilation of multiplication by a constant factor
       = O(arr.count * log_2(summedElementCount)) // Multiplication law for big O
       ```
     - It's unclear to me whether this is better or worse than `O((arr.count * log_2(arr.count)) + summedElementCount)`. If you know, please let me know in the comments below!

Comment: PERFECT! PERFECT! PERFECT!

Comment: This solution has O(nLog(n)) complexity and the problem can be solved in O(n)

Comment: @FabioFelici I don't think there's an `O(n)` solution in the general case (where `arr.count - summedElementCount != 1`), because maintaining a min-max heap still has logarithm performance on inserts. See my newly written point 7.

Comment: @Alexander See below

Answer (score 3):

Here

```
_ = sorted
    .filter({ $0 != sorted.last!})
    .map { minSum += $0 }
```

your expectation is that all but the largest element are added. But that is only correct it the largest element is *unique.* (And similarly for the maximal sum.)

Choosing an array with all identical errors makes the problem more apparent:

```
miniMaxSum(arr: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
// 0 0
```

A simpler solution would be to compute the sum of all elements once, and then get the result by subtracting the largest respectively smallest array element. I'll leave the implementation to you :)

Comment: Got it perfect, thank you. Never thought of that way!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the O(n) solution:

```
func miniMaxSum(arr: [Int]) {
    var smallest = Int.max
    var greatest = Int.min
    var sum = 0

    for x in arr {
        sum += x
        smallest = min(smallest, x)
        greatest = max(greatest, x)
    }

    print(sum - greatest, sum - smallest, separator: "  ")
}
```

Comment: This is great, but important to note that it doesn't generalize if `arr.count - summedElementCount != 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one accepted:

```
func miniMaxSum(arr: [Int]) -> Void {
    let sorted = arr.sorted()
    let minSum = sorted[0...3].reduce(0, +)
    let maxSum = sorted[1...4].reduce(0, +)
    print("\(minSum) \(maxSum)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
func miniMaxSum(arr: [Int]) -> Void {

var minSum = 0
var maxSum = 0
var minChecked = false
var maxChecked = false
let numMax = arr.reduce(Int.min, { max($0, $1) })
print("Max number in array: \(numMax)")

let numMin = arr.reduce(Int.max, { min($0, $1) })
print("Min number in array: \(numMin)")

for item in arr {

    if !minChecked && numMin == item {
        minChecked = true
    } else {
        maxSum = maxSum + item
    }

    if !maxChecked && numMax == item {
        maxChecked = true
    } else {
        minSum = minSum + item
    }
}
print("\(minSum) \(maxSum)")
}
```

Comment: You should offer an explanation of what's going on, and just paste some code. BTW ` { max($0, $1) }` is the same as just `max`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func miniMaxSum(arr: [Int]) -> Void {
let min = arr.min()
let max = arr.max()
let total = arr.reduce(0, +)
print(total - max!, total - min!, separator: " ")
}
```